# Bootstrap prograss bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I am using follwing tag for progress bar

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    60%
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the progress bar . BUt I need to change the value. Currently it is 60. When i changing "aria-valuenow" nothing happens to the progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the width also: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lsg1y8k/)

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%;">
    50%
  </div>
</div>
```